# Datatables with server side processing and custom search

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datatables

I'm developing a page with 3 views:

Index with 2 partial view
 - Search View
 - Result View

I want that result view got all data that I got on my database. So I use Datatables to display it.
But I want that it display with server side processing.

I got this on Index view:

```
 $('#table').DataTable({
            retrieve: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            searching: false,
            bInfo: false,
            ajax:
            {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetData")",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "JSON"
            },
        });
```

Its all ok, json object was returned.

My problem is when I click on the button (submit button inside form) I lost server side processing. this button call action result function on controller. And this function return a model with results (database data).

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: Warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Comment: no error? only warning?

Comment: YEs a Pop up with "Warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable".

Comment: ok..another thing I guess you are initilaizing table more than once...can you show a bit of code? sorry for late reply